# Apollo Client: How to query rest endpoint with query string?

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-link-rest

I'm using Apollo to call a rest endpoint that takes variables from query string:

`/api/GetUserContainers?showActive=true&showSold=true`

I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass variables to the query, so it can then call the correct url. From looking at [apollo-link-rest docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/rest/) and a few issues I think I'm supposed to use `pathBuilder` but this is not documented and I haven't been able to get it working.

So far I've defined my query like this:

```
getUserContainersQuery: gql`
  query RESTgetUserContainers($showActive: Boolean, $showSold: Boolean, $pathBuilder: any) {
    containerHistory @rest(type: "ContainerHistoryResponse", pathBuilder: $pathBuilder) {
      active @type(name: "UserContainer") {
        ...ContainerFragment
      }
      sold @type(name: "UserContainer") {
        ...ContainerFragment
      }
    }
  }
  ${ContainerFragment}
`
```

and calling it in my component like this, **which does not work**:

```
import queryString from 'query-string'

// ...

const { data } = useQuery(getUserContainersQuery, {
  variables: {
    showActive: true,
    showSold: false,
    pathBuilder: () => `/api/GetUserContainers?${queryString.stringify(params)}`,
  },
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
})
```

The only way I got this to work was by passing the fully constructed path to the query from the component:

```
// query definition

getUserContainersQuery: gql`
  query RESTgetUserContainers($pathString: String) {
    containerHistory @rest(type: "ContainerHistoryResponse", path: $pathString) { // <-- pass path here, instead of pathBuilder
      // same response as above
    }
  }
`

// component

const params = {
  showActive: true,
  showSold: false,
}

const { data } = useQuery(getUserContainersQuery, {
  variables: {
    pathString: `/api/GetUserContainers?${queryString.stringify(params)}`,
  },
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
})
```

These seems to me like a really hacky solution which I'd like to avoid.

**What is the recommended way to handle this query string problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use the `pathBuilder` for simple query string params. You can pass your params directly as variables to `useQuery` then pass then directly into teh `path` using the `{args.somearg}` syntax. The issue I see is you've not defined the variables your using for you query `containerHistory` bu only in the query alias `RESTgetUserQueries`. If updated is should look like this:

```js
// query definition

getUserContainersQuery: gql`
  query RESTgetUserContainers($showActive: Boolean, $showSold: Boolean) {
    // pass the variables to the query
    containerHistory(showActive:$showActive, showSold:$showSold) @rest(type: "ContainerHistoryResponse", path:"/api/GetUserContainers?showActive={args.showActive}&showSold={args.showTrue}") { 

     //.. some expected reponse

    }
  }
`

// component

const params = {
  showActive: true,
  showSold: false,
}

const { data } = useQuery(getUserContainersQuery, {
  variables: {
    showActive, 
    showSold
  },
  fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network',
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this solved my problem. Do you know where this might be documented?

Comment: It’s cryptically documented here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/rest/ under the @rest directive full options section. Admittedly it’s not 100% clear even from their example that it works this way!

Comment: @Rennzie what if we have a condition where if a query params is undefined it should not be sent. Any idea how can we achieve that??